# How to group test cases by file hierarchy to show test results in allure report

Tags: playwright, allure

I have Allure reporter integration to my Playwright test. My configuration files looks like the following

```
// @ts-check
const { defineConfig, devices } = require("@playwright/test");


/**
 * @see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration
 */
module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: [
    ["html"],
    [
      "allure-playwright",
      {
        detail: true,
        outputFolder: "my-allure-results",
        suiteTitle: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: "https://example.com",

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: "on-first-retry",
    screenshot: "only-on-failure",
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
      fullyParallel: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
      fullyParallel: true,
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
      fullyParallel: true,
    },
    
  ],

});
```

and when I run the test cases and create allure report, my test cases are grouped by the browsers. As in the following picture
[image: Allure Report screenshot]

and my file hierarchy looks like this

[image: File hierarchy]

Where as I would like my test cases to be grouped by my file hierarchy
.
How to configure/organize my test cases so they group by the file hierarchy?